# Is there any way to import postman collection into playwright?

Tags: automated-testing, test-automation-framework, postman, playwright

**Details:**

We have several thousand APIs in various postman collection. Our customer wants to have them customized accordingly, towards E-2-E testing. The customer would like to use Playwright for functional and API testing, especially because of the good functionality in the framework.

Unfortunately, even with intensive search, we have not yet found a way to import directly from Postman-Collection into Playwright.

- Have you possibly found a corresponding possibility?
- Are there other possibilities?
- Do you have an alternative?

Comment: I didnt find an easy way or a script to convert the postman test scripts to playwright scripts. Did anyone find a way?

Answer (score 1):

For Playwright... there is no import tool that I know of.  One option is to import Postman collections into ReadyAPI.  It is not a perfect process, as some data will be missing and you will need to clean up the tests after importing.  Another alternative is to keep your tests in Postman and use one of their test runners (Newman or Collection Runner).

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way to import Postman collections into Playwright. However, you can export the Postman collections as a JSON file and write a script to convert the data into Playwright test scripts.

Another alternative could be to use a tool like Newman, which allows you to run Postman collections from the command line. You can use Newman in combination with Playwright to run API tests.

Alternatively, you could consider using a test automation tool that has native support for Postman collections, such as Postman Pro or Postman Enterprise.

Answer (score 0):

Playwright doesn't have such functionality, but you can use [Dave Farley's DSL architecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JDD5EEJgpHU). This way, you can have the run scenarios, but with a dual behavior on the protocol drivers: One for UI, where you gonna use Playwright, and one for API, where you can [run Postman using Newman](https://learning.postman.com/docs/running-collections/using-newman-cli/command-line-integration-with-newman/).

[image]